# python imaging library: Can I simply fill my image with one color?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

How can I fill an existing image with a desired color?

(I am using `from PIL import Image` and `from PIL import ImageDraw`)

This command creates a new image filled with a desired color

```
image = Image.new("RGB", (self.width, self.height), (200, 200, 200))
```

But I would like to reuse the same image without the need of calling "new" every time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
image.paste(color, box)
```

where `box` can be a 2-tuple giving the upper left corner, a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate, or `None` (same as `(0, 0)`).

Since you want to fill the entire image, you can use the following:

```
image.paste( (200,200,200), (0, 0, image.size[0], image.size[1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to [draw a rectangle](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
#...
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.rectangle([(0,0),image.size], fill = (200,200,200) )
```

Or (untested):

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image).rectangle([(0,0),image.size], fill = (200,200,200) )
```

(Although it is surprising [there is no simpler method](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html) to fill a whole image with one background color, like `setTo` for opencv)