# How to add noise (dithering) at background only?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, dithering

I am trying to train a model with some noisy images having dithering.

**What I have :**

1. clean pdfs with white background
2. coloured pdfs(RGB) and grayscale pdfs (with 3 channels, RGB)

**What I want:**

3. convert only white background (not text) into gray background, if possible only half page should be converted
4. Add dithering to the gray background without loosing the text

**what I tried:**

```
import os

from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray


ORIGIN_PATH = "/home/dithering/temp/"
DESTIN_PATH = "/home/dithering`enter code here`/temp_try/"
"""for filename in os.listdir(ORIGIN_PATH):
    img = Image.open(ORIGIN_PATH + filename).convert("L")
    rbg_grayscale_img = img.convert("RGB")
    rbg_grayscale_img.save(DESTIN_PATH + filename)"""


for filename in os.listdir(ORIGIN_PATH):

    img = Image.open(ORIGIN_PATH + filename).convert("L", dither=Image.Dither.FLOYDSTEINBERG)

    # convert image to nparray
    numpydata = asarray(img)
    numpydata[numpydata > 250] = 128

    # data
    print(numpydata)

    # convert array to image
    final_image = Image.fromarray(numpydata)

    # img show
    final_image.show()

    # img save
    final_image.save(DESTIN_PATH + filename)
```

I expect something like this, [image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: generate an entirely "dithered"/noisy image (no content, just noise/dithering), the size of your subject image. get mask for background. use mask to copy dithering into subject image.

Comment: thank you @ChristophRackwitz, could you please also write some lines of code wrt the above idea?

Comment: start by generating a flat gray PIL image ([`image.paste(color, box)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548590/python-imaging-library-can-i-simply-fill-my-image-with-one-color)), then converting it to `mode="1"`, which will dither it.